# Is it possible to build PostGIS extensions without building the entire project?

Tags: postgis, postgresql-extensions, geocoding

PostGIS has an extension called [`postgis_tiger_geocoder`](https://github.com/ahinz/postgis/tree/master/extensions/postgis_tiger_geocoder), I have a few questions about it (all pretty tied together),

- Is it possible to build that without building the rest of PostGIS?
- If so, can I use the copy I build with my distro-installed PostGIS.

Ubuntu packages required to buildpostigs

```
xsltproc libgeos-dev libproj-dev libgdal-dev libjson0-dev docbook-xsl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this is simply *no*. While this may get fixed at some point in time, and it should be fixed soon for the sanity and great glory, until then you may find this useful

- [*What is the easiest way to install the latest postgis_tiger_geocoder?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162005/2639)