# What is the easiest way to install the latest postgis_tiger_geocoder?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, postgis, postgresql-extensions, geocoding

Ubuntu distributes PostGIS with a core extension called PostGIS TIGER Geocoder, packaged as `postgis_tiger_geocoder`. Currently, as of PostGIS 2.2.2, it pulls data from `TIGER2015`. I would like to upgrade this to pull from TIGER2016. I want to use the newest version of the geocoder. How do I go about this?

I want to upgrade just `postgis_tiger_geocoder`?

Comment: Does this help: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/postgis_installation.html#upgrade_tiger_geocoder

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's actually better than my own self-answer. If you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it. I couldn't find this on Google.

Comment: Or, I'll update my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they don't make this easy because it's part of core. It's also not fun that this is hard coded into the extension. You can either

1. Follow the instructions in [the official FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/postgis_installation.html#upgrade_tiger_geocoder) by extracting from the `.zip`
2. Rebuild the entirety of PostGIS which is a monstrously fun task -- though it is totally doable. There is no easy way to build *just* the extension. The extensions build after the documentation and the rest of PostGIS. Good luck and god speed.
3. Download PostGIS-Scripts from the [PDPG apt archive](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgis/). **Note, the file you want is labeled `postgresql-$majorversionpg-postgis-$majorversionpostgis-scripts_$fullversionpostgis` with the version of PostgreSQL and PostGIS. Do not download the transition packages that lack the `$majorversion` portion of the name.**

   1. After you download extract the files with `dpkg -X justDownloadedArchive.deb ./out`
   2. Copy `out/*geocoder*` to your extension folder (`/usr/share/postgresql/*/extension/`) *where `*` is some version number*.